# 'System.InvalidCastException' in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

The C# code:

```
         string d;
        d = "did" + mission.Text;
        int p = 0;

        var command = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [User] WHERE Username = @name", d);
        using (SqlCommand cBd = new SqlCommand(command, c))
        {
            cBd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtuser.Text);
            c.Open();
            p = (int)cBd.ExecuteScalar();
            c.Close();
        }
        p++;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET @mission = @par WHERE Username = @name",c);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mission", d);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par",p);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtuser.Text);
        c.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
```

The error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   App_Web_sazkdh0g.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: You should specify a column that you want to retrieve instead of `@g`. Column names are not vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?  It sounds like you are trying to send a parameter that does not match the type the command is expecting.

Comment: p = (int)cBd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: columns name can not be parametrized as sql parameter, must be given explicity

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @S.Akbari My understanding is: prepared parametrized queries can be optimized in SQL engine. Theoretically if column will be by parameter - can't be optimised

Comment: @JacekCz...Also we could say in regular SQL it's not doable to use parameters for column names but dynamic SQL could be an option.

Comment: Also, your SELECT command is still open to Sql Injection through the `d` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
            // In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //
                // Open the SqlConnection.
                //
                con.Open();
                //
                // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
                //
                string d;
                d = "did" + mission.Text;
                int p = 0;

                var command = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [User] WHERE Username = @name", d);
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtuser.Text);
                    p = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

                command = string.Format("UPDATE [User] SET {0} = @par WHERE Username = @name", d);
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par", p);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtuser.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
```

Possible `sql injection` in `string.Format`

Comment: i did it its working but it is not updatung the table why?

Comment: Use `Parameters` only for real parameters in your query, like values which standing after `>/</=` operators.

Comment: Set columns names in query string before with `string.Format`